# I tried to import (import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext) but it gives me error org.sprigframework cannot be resolved

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am trying to use getbeans method of applicationContext interface for that I tried to import springframework packages I have seen navin reddy videos where he used maven with the below dependency and he is able to import that packages but. Below is dependency I am using:

```
<dependencies>
<dependency> 
<groupId>junit</groupId> 
<artifactId>junit</artifactId> 
<version>3.8.1</version> <scope>test</scope> 
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
  <version>4.2.4 RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I expected that import problem supposed to be resolved so I can use applicationcontext object

Answer (score 1):

Correct one:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Wrong one:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
  <version>4.2.4 RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I guess spring does not have 4.2.4 RELEASE. Simply add (.) to 4.2.4.RELEASE

Comment: thank u for this it's working